# CICS parameters Update

Tags: mainframe, cics

I have recently updated the System Initialization Parameter file that is used t o override the default parameters.

So my question is that do i need to restart my CICS region or these parameters will be take automatically when i now connect to the CICS region.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends....Yes, you will have to restart the CICS to pick up the new parms from the SYSIN override, but

depending on the parms, same may be altered dynamically through CEMT.

Which parms did you change?

Answer (score 2):

If you only changed SYSIN parameters, then you have to recycle CICS. However, you can make many of the same changes dynamically via the CEMT transaction.

Which parameter(s) did you change?

Comment: Those can be updated by CEMT. SEE http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cics.ts.home.doc%2Flibrary%2Flibrary_pdf.html (for 4.1) for instructions on how to use CEMT to make the changes dynamically so you can schedule a bounce at an appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

If TCPIP was set to NO, and you now set it to YES, you will need to restart CICS. You can open or close TCPIP using the CEMT master console transaction, but if CICS was started with TCPIP=NO then the necessary programs won't be loaded into the system.